# How does the pronunciation of r change from "art" to "arth"

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

1) Does it change, even slightly, due weakening of the last consonant sound?
2) If it does what is this phenomenon called?

Comment: Do you mean, art→arθ? And is this specifically after r, or more general like "after vowels and r", etc?

Comment: Yes to the first question, i am not sure to the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general process is known a lenition, which unfortunately refers to very many different processes. The underlying idea is that *θ* is "weaker" than *t* (likewise *f,x* compared to *p,k*), and one of the environments where this happens is postvocalically (with or without a tautosyllabicity condition). However, the term also encompasses the changes *t → d,h,ʔ,ɾ*. Usually, such a lenition takes place right after a vowel or glide and not a consonant, so if "r" is included in the context, one may reasonable suspect that "r" is a vocoid *ɹ* as in English, and not a trill. The physical mechanism beneath the process is not clear, but seems to have to do with delaying the transition from a very open vocal tract to a closed one. If the process were triggered *only* by preceding *r* and not a vowel, that would be a typologically novel process.